# Facing issue with my Ubuntu 22.0 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, graphics, multiple-monitors, display

recently i observed that my display acting very wierdly.
Window manager warning: W30 appears to be one of the offending windows with a timestamp of 2186404
can anyone explain what is this error?

Also recently my windows display started showing inverted color then it went into an update after which i started facing this problem in my linux os. Sometimes i observe a line at the top of the screen having inverted colors.

Comment: We can't really explain an error without knowing the error. Please edit your question with the actual text of the error as well as the steps needed to reproduce. Please do not summarize in your own words. We need the actual error. Also, please choose a title that adequately summarizes and identifies your question. Ask Ubuntu is organized by question titles. Please no vague titles. "Issue with Ubuntu" could mean anything and isn't a good title. Add a comment tagging @nmath when you are finished editing the question.

Comment: You have the tags [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] and [tag:dual-boot] in this question.  It's *highly* unlikely you'd be asking a question about both dual-boot and WSL.  WSL is a *Microsoft* feature in Windows 10 and 11 that allows you to run Ubuntu as a feature.  Since you don't mention anything about this in your question, I'm guessing you really mean dual-boot.  I'm going to edit the WSL tag out, but if you really are using WSL, please add it back and edit the question  to clarify - Thanks!